# Abbreviations like 't', 'm', 'zt', 'sf' in chess databases

Tags: database, terminology

I am just cleaning up the `Event` and `Site` headers in the games in my chess database.

There are a lot of abbreviations there. I am relatively sure about the following:

- `of`, `qf`, `sf` and `f` – *octo final*, *quarter final*, *semi final* and *final*.
- `zt` and `izt`  – *zonal tournament* and *interzonal tournament*.

But I could need help with these:

- `tt` – *Transnational Tournament*? *Training Tournament*?
- `m` (also: `mt`) – *Masters*? *Match*? *Men*? *Memorial*?
- `Tch` – *Transnational Championship*?
- `It` – *Invitational Tournament*? *Italia*?

Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: m usually means match. Don't know about any of the others, sorry :/

Comment: Maybe an issue of "Chess Informant" has the info (and the same abbreviations)?

Comment: I compiled this database from different sources, and I think they use `m` for different meanings. I now fix it source by source and afterwards I merge them together. I remove everything except the [seven tag roster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation#Tag_pairs) to make progress. Still, lots of work with the "Event" and "Site" headers. The event header should contain the name of the event, like "XXII SuperGM" and the site header the name of the city/region followed by the [FIDE country code](https://www.olimpbase.org/help/help41.html), like "Linares ESP". Well, *should* :-/

Comment: @HaukeReddmann yes, I guess it comes from chess informant. But I can not find related info on the net. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_annotation_symbols) gives the symbols used inside of games, but not abbreviations used in event titles.

Comment: @NilsLindemann: Tomorrow I'm in the lib, which has a few recent issues. If I don't forget it, I take a look. No promises :-)

Comment: @NilsLindemann: Sorry, no luck. CI has only a few abbreviations, almost all of them (OK, "o"=olympiad) already mentioned. I also found an issue of "New In Chess", likewise a dead end.

Comment: @HaukeReddmann too bad, but thanks for taking the time :-)

Answer (score 2):

**tt** in databases means "team tournament" : you can find it for teams events, for instance the French team championship or Olympiads.

I suspect **Tch** to be similar ("Team championship") but I wouldn't be affirmative.

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia says `TT` is *Transposition Table*...

When the search encounters a transposition, it is beneficial to 'remember' what was determined last time the position was examined, rather than redoing the entire search again. For this reason, chess programs have a transposition table, which is a large hash table storing information about positions previously searched, how deeply they were searched, and what we concluded about them. Even if the depth (draft) of the related transposition table entry is not big enough, or does not contain the right bound for a cutoff, a best (or good enough) move from a previous search can improve move ordering, and save search time. This is especially true inside an iterative deepening framework, where one gains valuable table hits from previous iterations.

`IT` seems to hint at *Invitational Tournament*, though I cannot confirm this.

Comment: Ok, but I would guess `tt` does not mean that in the context of an `[Event "..."]` or `[Site "..."]` PGN header. Scid would store that somewhere else. Yes, I am also more and more sure that `It` means "Invitational Tournament".